# Convert column to rows, with separator "-" , ";"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Input :

```
      select(Emp_no, ADate, Atime)
```

---

```
      12333,     12-02-2013,    09.12 - 12.30
      12333,     12-02-2013,    12.32 - 17.30   

      13444,     12-02-2013,    09.10 - 18.30

      14444,     12-02-2013,    09.13 - 12.30
      14444,     12-02-2013,    17.20
```

Output :

```
      12333,     12-02-2013,    09.12 - 12.30 ; 12.32 - 17.30
      13444,     12-02-2013,    09.10 - 18.30
      14444,     12-02-2013,    09.13 - 12.30 ; 17.20
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use something similar to this to concatenate the multiple rows into a single row:

```
select distinct t1.Emp_no,
  t1.ADate, 
  STUFF(
         (SELECT '; ' + cast(t2.Atime as varchar(50))
          FROM yourtable t2
          where t1.Emp_no = t2.Emp_no
            and t1.ADate = t2.ADate
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS Atime
from yourtable t1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1588c/3)

Or you can use a `CROSS APPLY` with `FOR XML PATH`:

```
select distinct t1.Emp_no,
  t1.ADate, 
  left(t2.Atime, len(t2.atime)-1) ATime
from yourtable t1
cross apply
(
  select t2.Atime + '; '
  from yourtable t2
  where t1.Emp_no = t2.Emp_no
    and t1.ADate = t2.ADate
  FOR XML PATH('')
) t2 (Atime)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1588c/13)